# audio volume from external device

Tags: yocto, volume, alsa

I am working on a device with a imx6 with yocto linux (krogoth). I use headsets with usb and they works fine. But now I have a headset where it is possible to change the volume with two buttons on the device. On my windows notebook the volume control in the software changes when i push one of the buttons. I also tested it with a ubuntu 20 and I see the control in the ALSA mixer when a button is pushed.

On my device I see no reaction. The sound volume changes in the headset when a button is pushed but in the ALSA mixer of the device there is no reaction. That is a big problem for my use case. Does anybody knows this problem and can help me. Do I need a special module or anything else?

Comment: Ok, so you use bluetooth audio in your yocto build, based on your statement above. And now, you have a bluetooth headset that can adjust volume via bluetooth commands, and that doesn't work? Or it does, but the volume changes locally to the headset? This feels like a bluetooth audio question to me, not a Yocto question.

Comment: No it is no bluetooth device it is a normal USB Headset.

Comment: Hmm, the Krogoth version of alsa seems to be fairly recent. I would try this on any alsa suport forums you might find. I don't believe this would be a Yocto problem, but more likely, how to best use alsa problem.